# Обработка JSON в Python

Tags: python, json

Есть JSON вот такого вида. 15 - ID, он не статичен и всегда изменяется, какой-то определенной закономерности в этом нет. Нужно получить строки user, pass, port, ip и сделать это универсально.

```
{
 "status": "yes",
 "user_id": "1",
 "balance": 42.5,
 "currency": "RUB",
 "count": 1,
 "price": 6.3,
 "price_single": 0.9,
 "period": 7,
 "country": "ru",
 "list": {
   "15": {
      "id": "15",
      "ip": "2a00:1838:32:19f:45fb:2640::330",
      "host": "185.22.134.250",
      "port": "7330",
      "user": "5svBNZ",
      "pass": "iagn2d",
      "type": "http",
      "date": "2016-06-19 16:32:39",
      "date_end": "2016-07-12 11:50:41",
      "unixtime": 1466379159,
      "unixtime_end": 1468349441,
      "active": "1"
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: json, очевидно лежит в файле?

Comment: в каком формате обитает json, он у тебя, как словарь python, или как ?

Comment: бывает, что несколько id (как 15)?

Comment: id генерируется по принципу id++, но тк. я не единственный пользователь данного сайта, предсказать какой id будет следующим я не могу, json получаю get запросом к сайту.

Comment: так.. вы получаете json, как str?

Comment: ```response = requests.get('https://proxy6.net/api/{apicode}/buy?count=1&period=3&country=ru&version=6&type=socks')
id = str(response.json())```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

здесь код будет печатать все id, которые он найдёт

```
import json

text = '''{
 "status": "yes",
 "user_id": "1",
 "balance": 42.5,
 "currency": "RUB",
 "count": 1,
 "price": 6.3,
 "price_single": 0.9,
 "period": 7,
 "country": "ru",
 "list": {
   "15": {
      "id": "15",
      "ip": "2a00:1838:32:19f:45fb:2640::330",
      "host": "185.22.134.250",
      "port": "7330",
      "user": "5svBNZ",
      "pass": "iagn2d",
      "type": "http",
      "date": "2016-06-19 16:32:39",
      "date_end": "2016-07-12 11:50:41",
      "unixtime": 1466379159,
      "unixtime_end": 1468349441,
      "active": "1"
   }
 }
}'''

data = json.loads(text)['list']

for ID in data:
    data_id = data[ID]
    my_attrs = [
        data_id.get(attr) for attr in ["user", "pass", "port", "ip"]
    ]

    print(f"{ID=}: {'  '.join(my_attrs)}")
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно)

Comment: я увидел, что в запросе фигурирует конкретное ID, может сделать так, чтобы искало этот ID?

Comment: если вам понравился ответ, вы можете проголосовать за него (upvote)

Comment: Я так и сделал, еще раз спасибо)

Comment: вы подтвердили ответ, а также есть стрелочки(или треугольники), одна вверх, другая - вниз, я говорю про стрелочку вверх

Comment: Я тыкнул на нее но из за низкой репутации его не показывает но он учитывается, как мне сказало уведомление при нажатии

Comment: Да, всё учитывается, не парься, всё ок